# Sylow's theorem and uniqueness of normal supgroup

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $pq,$ where  $p$ and $q$ are primes such that $p < q.$ Then how to prove that $G$ has a unique normal subgroup of order $q?$

Comment: You have written a statement which ends with a ? but what's the question.

Comment: Sylow group not yalow group

Comment: How can I prove there is a unique normal subgroup of order q?

Comment: By Sylow's theorem there exists P Sylow p-subgroup and Q Sylow q-subgroup ,and np\q where np≡1 mod p then np=q which means there exists q number of Sylow p-subgroup which means that these are not normal. And nq\p where nq≡1 mod q but p<q then nq =1 which means that Q is unique normal subgroup.Is this enough proof?

Comment: There is no need to assume that $q \equiv 1 \bmod p$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $G$ is a group of order $pq$ and $p|pq\ \&\  p^2 \nmid pq,\ G$ has a  $p$-Sylow subgroup of order $p.$ Since the number of $p$-Sylow subgroups is of the form $1+kp,k\geq 0$, and which is a divisor of order of $G,$

We have $1+kp\ |\ pq.$

$\implies  1+kp|q,$ since $(1+kp,p)=1$

$\implies k=0$

Hence the $p$-Sylow subgroup,say $H,$ in the group of order $pq$ is unique.

Since $H$ and $xHx^{-1}$ are subgroups of same order and $H$ is the unique subgroup of order $p,$ we have $H=xHx^{-1},\ \forall x \in G.$

$ \ \ $ i.e., $Hx=xH \ \forall x \in G$. Therefore $H$ is normal.

Comment: @John Sorry to interpret this question. As  Derek Holt pointed out $p|q-1$ is need not to be true in this case thats why i did